# In Atom keymaps, what does ^ mean?

Tags: atom-editor, keymapping

In an Atom keymap config file, you may encounter something like

```
    "ctrl-tab": "pane:show-next-recently-used-item",
    "ctrl-tab ^ctrl": "pane:move-active-item-to-top-of-stack",
```

What does the `^` mean? The "in-depth" [documentation](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/) seems to make no mention of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Appears](https://github.com/atom/atom-keymap/blob/318bd74b2ba31ede8b005a835d67fb699403a537/src/helpers.coffee#L121) (based on how it constructs a textual representation of the binding) to specify `keyup`. So I believe the second command you provided will trigger after releasing the `ctrl` key, after running the first command at least once.